# Add class in html tag with JQuery if another class already exist

Tags: jquery, html, class

I'm trying to add a class with JQuery in an HTML tag (table).

I would like to add this class just in case another class exist (in this way I'm going to select just the rights tables, just the tables with that class)

I also have some tables which already have this class (class to add) so I have to avoid to add the class another time in these tables.

This is the table where I want to add the class:

```
<table class="shop_table my_account_orders">
</table>
```

And this is the table which is already correct:

```
<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">
</table>
```

So, I would like to have all the tables like the second one:

```
<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">
</table>
```

I would like to add "shop_table_responsive" in the tables where is missing and where "shop_table" (I have it in all my tables) already exist.

This is what I tried:

```
if( jQuery('table').hasClass('.shop_table') === true )
{
 jQuery('table').addClass('shop_table_responsive');
}
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to bother with an `if` statement to check for the `shop_table` class, just use the selector to match the correct elements.  There's also no need to detect whether the element already has the `shop_table_responsive` class on it. Just add it; if it was already there nothing will happen.

This is all you need to do:

```
$('table.shop_table').addClass('shop_table_responsive');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$('#id').hasClass('myClass1')){$('#id').addClass('myClass2')}
```

Comment: provide an explanation of the code you proposed as an answer.  Code lines by themselves are not sufficient for helping the OP understand and get better at coding.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using toggleclass method.

```
$(selector).toggleclass(class);
```